# How to read from terminal to int list in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, user-input

I want to prompt the user to enter 2 numbers into a list of ints, add the 2 numbers and append the result to the list, and finally subtract the 2 numbers and append the result to the list. This was an assignment given to us while learning C. I'm trying to learn Python myself using the same assignments. My code won't append the results of the equations to the array. The error says list indices should be integers not tuples. Here's my code:

```
numarray=[]

num1 = int(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))
num3 = num1+num2
num4 = num1-num2

print numarray[num1,num2,num3,num4]
```

Comment: `list[..]` is an index operation and `,` creates a tuple. Thus, `numarray[num1,num2,num3,num4]` has the types `list[tuple]` which is not allowed which is precisely what the error message says: "indices should be integers not tuples". (It has nothing to do with *reading* values.)

Comment: @pst I don't understand your post at all. How would I correct the syntax of my code so? Is it the definition of the list or how I'm defining them in the `print numarray`statement? I'm really new to python so need baby steps with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the array elements like this:

```
numarray = [num1, num2, num3, num4]
```

Alternatively, you could actually append the values like you specified in the your text:

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))
numarray = [num1, num2]
numarray.append(num1 + num2)
numarray.append(num1 - num2)
```

Then to access the elements, you use the same notation as C (e.g. `numarray[0]` would be the first element).

Answer (score 1):

After you set all of the num* variables, you should then do this:

```
numarray = [num1, num2, num3, num4]

print numarray
```

The call `numarray[num1,num2,num3,num4]` is illegal because the `list[]` syntax is used for accessing the given index of the list, not setting items in the list.